# Why am I getting these errors warning: expression result unused [-Wunused-value]

Tags: c++, xcode, debugging

1 warning generated.
makeInFile.cpp:55:17: error: expected ';' after expression

```
B = new Item {key, NULL};
            ^
            ;
```

makeInFile.cpp:55:19: warning: expression result unused [-Wunused-value]

```
 B = new Item {key, NULL};
              ^~~
```

makeInFile.cpp:55:28: error: expected ';' after expression

```
 B = new Item {key, NULL};
                       ^
                       ;
```

makeInFile.cpp:55:24: warning: expression result unused [-Wunused-value]

```
B = new Item {key, NULL};
                   ^~~~
```

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/clang/7.0.0/include/stddef.h:100:18: note: 
      expanded from macro 'NULL'
  define NULL __null

Some source code, this is using a hashtable.

```
Item *B;

string str;
ifstream inFile (fName);



if (inFile.is_open())
{

    for (int i=1; (getline (inFile,str)) && i<=num; i++) {

          cout << str << endl;





        B = new Item {str, NULL};
        table.insertItem(B);
```

In Xcode it was working perfectly, until I ran it on Terminal.

Comment: Can you please show us more context, or at least try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us? And how do you build the source, what flags do you pass to the compiler?

Comment: Are you compiling with c++11 enabled?

Comment: Post a [mcve]; what's `Item`? And do something about the code formatting, please.

Comment: @JonathanPotter thank you that was my problem.